# React-plotly, update scattermapbox zoom and center

Tags: reactjs, plotly.js

I have an application with a scattermapbox starting with a whole-world view. When the user loads some lat/lon points, the program calculates a sensible centre and zoom and updates the react component accordingly.

Unfortunately, the centre only sometimes works. Displaying the points and zooming always works.

Here is a minimal executable example showcasing the problem.

Clicking the button should zoom to a point in England, centring the map on the data point. Unfortunately, it centres the map on a point in France.

Some observations:

- This code reproduces the problem for me in both Chrome and Safari.
- Clicking the button a second time will centre the map correctly.
- Clicking the button then clicking a modebar zoom button will snap the
  map display to the correct point.
- This is very sensitive to the
  numbers. For example, changing the initial zoom from 0.9 to 1 will
  fix the problem in this demo. Unfortunately, the same change does not
  fix the issue in my real app.

Any hints as to what I may be doing wrong will be gratefully received.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
import settings from './settings.json';

class MapPositionSpike extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      center: {lon: 0, lat: 0},
      zoom: 0.9
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Plot 
          data={[{type: "scattermapbox", lon: [-1], lat: [52]}]}
          layout={{
            margin: {'l':0, 'r':0, 'b':0, 't':0},
            mapbox: {
              accesstoken: settings["mapbox_access_token"],
              center: this.state.center,
              zoom: this.state.zoom
            }
          }}
          style={{height: '660px', width: '660px'}}
        />
        <button 
          onClick={e => this.setState({
            center: {lon: -1, lat: 52}, 
            zoom: 7
          })}
        >Click Me!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MapPositionSpike />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Hi @Ken White. Thanks for tidying up the title. I couldn't find a tag for react-plotly, which is the library I am using to access reactjs. Would it be appropriate to add it back to the title or is there a better way to highlight that information?

Comment: Why aren't the react.js and plotly.js tags sufficient?

Comment: Plotly.js draws charts. React.js renders components. React-plotly wraps plotly.js, allowing it to be used as a react component. The library I am using -- probably misusing -- is react-plotly.

Comment: Fair enough. :-) I  reverted my edit to restore the original title. Thanks for the explanation - it will help prevent the same mistake in the future.